# Does Opacity attribute change pixel value

Tags: html, css, image-processing, html5-canvas

Suppose I have a HTML document with CSS property Opacity = 1.0. Then I change its opacity to ".5". And I took two screen shots there (before and after change in opacity). Have pixel values of images been changed? If they have, how can I detect that how much opacity has been changed using pixel values of both images(one before change and one after change)? 
How can I use HTML5 canvas element here?

Thanks

Comment: first of all, opacity isn't related in any way to font-size.
secondly, i don't really understand what is the issue- maybe try to explain it better and attach some code samples.

Comment: pixel values WILL NOT change by modifying the opacity.

Comment: Even in the screenshots because these images are different as user perceives. The only way to happen that is pixel values are different.

Comment: Do you have screenshots available?

Comment: Yes, I have. You can take screenshots. See- http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html

Comment: Interesting; there is definitely a difference. In Safari it looks like canvas renders text using `-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your pixel values will change.

Your monitor uses colors in rgba format which displays a color based on its red,green,blue and alpha (opacity) components.

If you change the opacity of your image each pixel will have its alpha value changed accordingly.

An exception is when you've applied 2 overlapping images (such as applying 2 background images).

The exception causes all the rgba values of the resulting composite image to change.

The exception will trigger an irreversible color mixing using a formula similar to this:

```
alpha = 1 - (1 - topImage.A) * (1 - backImage.A);
red = topImage.R * topImage.A / r.A + backImage.R * backImage.A * (1 - topImage.A) / r.A;
green = topImage.G * topImage.A / r.A + backImage.G * backImage.A * (1 - topImage.A) / r.A;
blue = topImage.B * topImage.A / r.A + backImage.B * backImage.A * (1 - topImage.A) / r.A;
```

Your second question is a Maybe.

If you saved your alpha adjusted image to a format that supports rgba (like .png), you can draw the .png onto canvas and read the rgba pixel values using this canvas context method.

If you saved your alpha adjusted image to a format that doesn't support alpha values (like .jpg), the opacity values are gone.

Here's how to use canvas to read the opacity (alpha):

```
// get references to canvas and its context
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var context=canvas.getContext("2d");

// draw the image onto canvas
context.drawImage(yourImage,0,0);

// get an array containing the rgba values for each pixel
// this array has 4 elements for each pixel: r,g,b,a
// the values range from 0-255
var imageData = context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
var data = imageData.data;

// assuming the opacity was change over the whole image
// you can get the alpha (opacity) be reading the 4th array value
var red = data[0];
var green = data[1];
var blue = data[2];
var alpha = data[3];  // values [0-255]
```

If your image is an html img element, you can even supply a reference to that element as "yourImage" above.  One warning you will get a cross-origin failure if the image source of your html img element is not hosted on the same domain as your web page (google CORS security).